# Calculation in Nested Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, nested-loops

I'm using a data sample looking like that :

```
| Parent     | Child    | Order | Quantity | 
|:-----------|:--------:| -----:|---------:|
| Meal       | Element 1| 10    |1         |
| Meal       | Element 2| 20    |1         |
| Element 1  | Recipe 1 | 10    |0.2       |
| Element 1  | Recipe 2 | 20    |0.5       |
| Recipe 1   | Recipe 3 | 10    |0.1       |
| Recipe 3   | Raw Mat1 | 10    |1         |
| Element 2  | Recipe 4 | 10    |0.6       |
| Element 2  | Recipe 5 | 20    |0.3       |
| Recipe 4   | Recipe 6 | 10    |1.2       |
| Recipe 6   | Raw Mat2 | 10    |1.5       |
```

I know the unit weight of each Recipe and Raw material but I need to calculate the weight of Element1 and 2 as well as Meal parent, which depends from the calculated weight of both elements.

My result should look like that :

```
| Material   | Order full   | Quantity | U.Weight | 
|:-----------|:------------:| --------:|---------:|
| Meal       | /            | 1        | TOBECALC | --0.2*1+0.5*1 + 0.6*1+0.3*1
| Element 1  | /10          | 1        | TOBECALC | --0.2*1+0.5*1
| Recipe 1   | /10/10       | 0.2      | 1        |
| Recipe 3   | /10/10/10    | 0.02     | 1        |
| Raw Mat1   | /10/10/10/10 | 0.02     | 1        |
| Recipe 2   | /10/20       | 0.5      | 1        |
| Element 2  | /20          | 1        | TOBECALC | --0.6*1+0.3*1
| Recipe 4   | /20/10       | 0.6      | 1        |
| Recipe 6   | /20/10/10    | 0.72     | 1        |
| Raw Mat2   | /20/10/10/10 | 1.08     | 1        |
| Recipe 5   | /20/20       | 0.3      | 1        |
```

Here is what I did so far :
A procedure PROC_INCO calling PROC_DETAILED_INCO calling PROC_UNIT_INCO that inserts lines in the final table. PROC_DETAILED_INCO is recursively called for each child and this is where I implemented the weight calculation.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_UNIT_INCO
     (IN ID_ARTICLE INTEGER,
     IN ID_ROOT_EXE INTEGER,
     IN T_ORDER_FULL VARCHAR(100),
     IN QUANTITY FLOAT,
     OUT U_WEIGHT FLOAT)
     
     BEGIN
     
     DECLARE WEIGHT FLOAT;
     
   SELECT F_WEIGHT INTO WEIGHT FROM MATERIAL WHERE I_ID = ID_ARTICLE;
         
         IF T_ORDER_FULL IS NULL THEN
         SET T_ORDER_FULL = '/';
         END IF;
         
         IF TYPEART IN ('RawMat','Recipe') THEN 
         SET WEIGHT = WEIGHT;
         SET U_WEIGHT = WEIGHT * QUANTITY;
         ELSE
         SET WEIGHT = 0;
         SET U_WEIGHT = 0;
         END IF;
      
  INSERT INTO FINAL_RESULT (T_CODE, TT_ORDER_FULL, F_WEIGHT, F_QUANTITY, I_ID_ROOT_EXE)
  VALUES(CODEART, T_ORDER_FULL, WEIGHT, QUANTITY, ID_ROOT_EXE);
     
     END$$
 
 
 CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_DETAILED_INCO
      (IN ID_ARTICLE INTEGER,
     IN ID_ROOT_EXE INTEGER,
     IN T_ORDER_FULL VARCHAR(100),
     IN QUANTITY FLOAT,
     OUT CHILD_WEIGHT FLOAT)
      
      BEGIN
    DECLARE IS_DONE INT DEFAULT FALSE;
       DECLARE ID_CHILD INTEGER;
       DECLARE TEMP_ORDER INTEGER;
       DECLARE NEW_ORDER_FULL VARCHAR(100);
       DECLARE TYPE INTEGER;
       
       DECLARE CHILD_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
       SELECT A.CHILD, A.ORDER, QUANTITY * A.QUANTITY  AS QUANTITY
       FROM BOM A
       INNER JOIN MATERIAL B ON A.CHILD = B.CODE
       WHERE A.PARENT = ID_ARTICLE
       ORDER BY A.ORDER;
       
       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET IS_DONE = TRUE;
       
       CALL PROC_UNIT_INCO (ID_ARTICLE, ID_ROOT_EXE, T_ORDER_FULL, QUANTITY, @U_WEIGHT);
       SET @FIN_WEIGHT:= 0;
       SELECT @U_WEIGHT INTO CHILD_WEIGHT;
       
       OPEN FILS_CURSOR;
       get_list: LOOP
       FETCH FILS_CURSOR INTO ID_CHILD, TEMP_ORDER, QUANTITY, PERTE;
       IF IS_DONE THEN
       LEAVE get_list;
       END IF;
       SET NEW_ORDER_FULL = CONCAT(COALESCE(T_ORDER_FULL,''),'/',lpad(cast(TEMP_ORDER AS char(200)),5,'0'));
       
       CALL PROC_DETAILED_INCO(ID_CHILD, ID_ROOT_EXE, NEW_ORDER_FULL, QUANTITY, @CHILD_WEIGHT);
              
--this is where i want to calculate my weight by summing my children's weight       
SET @FIN_WEIGHT := @FIN_WEIGHT + @CHILD_WEIGHT;      
       
       END LOOP get_list;
       
       IF TYPE NOT IN ('RawMat','Recipe') THEN 
       
       UPDATE FINAL_RESULT SET F_WEIGHT = @FIN_WEIGHT WHERE TT_ORDER_FULL = T_ORDER_FULL;
       
       END IF;
       CLOSE FILS_CURSOR;
        
      END$$
     
    CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_INCO
      (IN CODE_ART VARCHAR(50))
      
      BEGIN
      DECLARE ID_ARTICLE INTEGER;
      
      SELECT I_ID INTO ID_ARTICLE FROM MATERIAL WHERE T_CODE = CODE_ART;
   DELETE FROM DETAILED_INCO WHERE I_ID_ROOT_EXE = ID_ARTICLE;
      
      CALL PROC_DETAILED_INCO (ID_ARTICLE, ID_ARTICLE, NULL, 1, @CHILD_WEIGHT);
      select
   *
   from final_result
   order by tt_order_full;
   END$$
   
DELIMITER ;
     
CALL PROC_INCO ('Meal');
```

Apologies if there is any mistakes, I simplified the procedure for better readability.
The weight calculation is not working as I want it... I do not really understand the calculated weight that I obtain but it seems that it resets each time the procedure enters in the loop and then fetches the latest child weight at the parent level.

Thanks in advance for your help on this,

Nico

Comment: switch to mysql 8 and recursive cte that is a better solution

Comment: I’m already using mysql8. Recursive cte is ok for top bottom calculation like order or quantity in my example. But the weight needs a bottom up calculation after the top bottom quantity calculation. 
Here is why I believe I cannot do it easily with recursive cte.